# AVCaptureConnection setVideoOrientation during Recording

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have a problem with the video orientation during recording.

I'm using an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to record a video using `AVFoundation`.
Before starting the recording I have no problem to set the video Orientation using the `AVCaptureConnection setVideoOrientation` method.

However if a video recording is already running, changing the `AVCaptureConnection` `VideoOrientation` doesn't change the real orientation on the file that is being written.

Is this a known limitation, or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild thought, but can you pause the recording and change the orientation? Or perhaps stop it and restart immediately? changing the orientation in the stop/start process? The question&answer I find on this  suggests to me that you can not make this change mid flight..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html

That said there is an interesting nano note on doing mid-flight changes here ...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

Read down and you'll find ...

Switching Between Devices
Sometimes you may want to allow users to switch between input devices—for example, switching from using the front-facing to to the back-facing camera. To avoid pauses or stuttering, you can reconfigure a session while it is running, however you should use beginConfiguration and commitConfiguration to bracket your configuration changes:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = <#A capture session#>;
[session beginConfiguration];

[session removeInput:frontFacingCameraDeviceInput];
[session addInput:backFacingCameraDeviceInput];

[session commitConfiguration];
```

When the outermost commitConfiguration is invoked, all the changes are made together. This ensures a smooth transition. So [session beginConfiguration] change your AVCaptureConnection VideoOrientation if you can and [session commitConfiguration]. Let us know if it works!

Comment: If you commit a new `AVCaptureSession` configuration, the recording stops. Only solution is as you said to stop and restart recording, but this adds extra complexity which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: How about if you switch devices as it suggests here; maybe there is something in this?